# React Native Text Input place the text on bottom of the input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a text input in react native and by default, the text is centered in the input box

Is there a way to have the text on the bottom of the input, as if there is 0 padding between the bottom border of the input box and the text?

```
<TextInput
   type='submit'
   style={styles.input}
   onChangeText={text => this.setState({ name: text })}
   title='Name'
   value={this.state.name}
/>
```

```
input: {
        height: 40,
        width: 250,
        margin: 12,
        borderRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderBottomWidth: 1 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use textAlignVertical:'bottom', paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom:0, which aligns the text to bottom in TextInput

```
input: {
height: 40,
width: 250,
margin: 12,
borderRadius: 0,  
backgroundColor: 'white',
borderBottomWidth: 1 , 
textAlignVertical:'bottom', paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom:0,
}
```